# Sticky footer only if content overflows viewport

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a footer element that is inline only if the content is overflowing the viewport, in which case it becomes sticky, bottom fixed. The use case would be to have some functional button always visible on long data grids.

I remember doing this with a hack many years ago but I forgot :) I know it could be done with Javascript but is there a more streamlined way to do it only with CSS?

When content is shorter than the viewport

```
------< viewport top 
header
content
[footer, inline]


------ < viewport bottom
```

When content overflows the viewport

```
------< viewport top 
header
content
content
content
[footer, sticky]
------ < viewport bottom
content
content
content
```

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

How about using max-height and calc? Header and footer need to have a fixed width:

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/OPBGjx

HTML:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
  content<br>
  [...]
  content<br>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 150px - 100px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```